# Is it possible to load webfonts through the offline storage cache manifest?

Tags: html, manifest, webfonts

I understand that I can import my fonts through html/css but I am wondering if this is a achievable approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, if you add fonts to your manifest file they will be downloaded along with the rest of the files, and then be available offline.  <strike>The fonts will need to be available from the same server where your offline app is, because you can't cache resources not on your domain.  You couldn't cache a Google Web Font, for instance.</strike>  I've been doing some testing on this, it seems fonts from Google are cached fine on Chrome and Opera, [only Firefox has problems](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687758).  The 'not on your domain' restriction for the manifest only applies when it's served over HTTPS.

You will still need to reference the fonts with a `@font-face` rule in your CSS for them to be used in your page.  For example, in your manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1
index.html
style.css
GenBasR-webfont.eot
GenBasR-webfont.woff
GenBasR-webfont.ttf
GenBasR-webfont.svg
```

In style.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GentiumBasicRegular';
    src: url('GenBasR-webfont.eot');
    src: url('GenBasR-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('GenBasR-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('GenBasR-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('GenBasR-webfont.svg#webfontLblSsz1O') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'GentiumBasicRegular';
}
```

Get the Gentium files from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Gentium-Basic).

Comment: Super sweet! I'm going to be using this in the future for sure!

Comment: when you'd like to download all google font formats, check out this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300143/how-to-download-multiple-formats-of-a-web-font-from-the-official-google-web-fo