# Download multiple formats of a font from the Google Web Fonts?

Tags: webfonts, google-webfonts

I've learnt that Google automatically serves TTF, EOT, WOFF, or SVG font files depending on the browser / device it's accessed from.

Now I am planning to host and serve the font files from my server itself, for which I would first have to download all the file formats of the web font(s).

How or where can I download the 4 file formats for a web font that I would like to use?

PS: By using different browsers -- Chrome, IE9 and Safari (dev - iPhone UA), I was able to get the WOFF, EOT and TTF formats. No luck with the SVG format though. It would be awesome if there's an even simpler way.

EDIT: Oh, and by the way, I do know that I can download various formats from [online web fonts](http://www.onlinewebfonts.com/), but I am talking about downloading from the official repo here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download multiple formats of a web font from the (official) Google Web Fonts repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300143/how-to-download-multiple-formats-of-a-web-font-from-the-official-google-web-fo)

Answer (score 0):

You can download all the Google Fonts directly from the Github repository (**google/fonts**), but as you know, only the ttf/otf format. So with those fonts, you can generate a web font kit using [Fontprep](https://github.com/briangonzalez/fontprep) or with the generator of [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

I hope it will help !

Comment: Thanks ! You save me so much time !