# What is the proper syntax for preloading a variable font?

Tags: html, css, syntax, preload, variable-fonts

I want to preload a local Google variable font, and was wondering if either of these is correct. Specifically, I'm asking about the MIME type. If there's an issue with either of these, please let me know!

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth-wght.ttf" as="font" type="font/truetype" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/Inconsolata-VariableFont_wdth-wght.ttf" as="font" type="font/truetype-variations" crossorigin>
```

I tried the "type='font/truetype'" but wasn't sure if that's accurate.

Comment: You can inspect the results in dev tools. You don't need the special `-variation` format identifiers. But you should consider switching to woff2 as it is significantly smaller. Using truetype kind of undermines the goal of a fast font delivery. See ["Variable Font Hosting, Syntax and why does Google not provide WOFF2 download for self hosting varibale fonts?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625073/variable-font-hosting-syntax-and-why-does-google-not-provide-woff2-download-for/78227993#78227993)

Comment: Thanks!  Yah, everything else I use is woff2, but I needed the ultra-expanded form, and was unable to figure out how to get a woff2 version of that one.  I might just switch to woff2 for the regular versions and use the standard ultra-expanded ttf version.  That will save me about 150K.

Comment: You may also fetch the woff2 from the static API query (select "one value" option in the gfont UI) Open `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wdth@200` and download the woff2 specified in the src property. variable fonts are larger in filesize than single style (static) equivalents

Comment: The two comments above answered all the questions I had.  Thank you both!