# Chrome blocks request for google fonts when using appcache

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, html5-appcache, google-font-api

I am using Roboto from googlefonts.

`<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

After adding HTML5 Application Cache chrome blocks the request for the css file.

[image]

Without using Application Cache (simply removing `manifest="myApp.appcache"`) everything is fine.
Could anybody explain me why this happens and how to fix this?

Note: The CSS-file is not added to the application cache manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe any resources not included in the .appcache file are blocked.

Comment: no. Resources of the same domain are not blocked. Only resources of other domains.

Comment: Either way wouldn't fonts.googleapis.com be a different domain than your app?

Comment: Of course but thats not the "why this happens" it's just "what happens". I don't see any good reason for chrome to behave like this

Comment: Ok, but to confirm, you do have the google css file listed in your .appcache manifest file?  This post seems similar but is more specifically asking how to add the something from the Google font API to the cache manifest file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882954/html5-offline-cache-google-font-api

Comment: No the Google CSS file is not listed in the appcache manifest. Seems that this is not possible. I know how to host the font files localy but i don't want to provide all font files for all browsers. But even if i just add the css file as stylesheet the request is blocked by chrome